# length of table read from a data file in r

Tags: r

I have a simple table with the following entries.

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

The file name is "test.txt". I have used the following command to read in the file.

```
mydata<-read.table("test.txt")
```

But when I enter 
    `length(mydata)`
it shows 1 instead of 5. Why does it show 1 and not 5 ?

Comment: It gives the number of columns  ie. `ncol(mydata)` or `length(mydata)` will be the same.  If you need `5`, then `length(mydata[,1])` or `nrow(mydata)`

Comment: Thanks akrun! How to convert this data into a vector of the data elements whose length would be 5 ?

Comment: Just do `mydata[,1]` as you have one column or `unlist(mydata)`

Comment: Thanks once again! it works! Can you briefly explain me the background info as to how it worked ?

Comment: Here, we are converting the data.frame which has 2 dimensions (row, column) to a vector with just one dimension (length)

Comment: Thanks again!  What is I needed to convert a vector into 2 dimension data frame ?

Comment: If `v1` is a vector, then `dat <- data.frame(v1)` should be a data.frame

Comment: Thanks arun for helping me with the basics!

Comment: You might get better grasp by reading the introduction materials in R.

Answer (score 7):

I believe

```
nrow(mydata)
```

should return the number of rows (5)

Comment: Yes icanbenchurat , it does return!

Answer (score 0):

The length of the data frame will give you number of columns present in the data-frame. In this case it is 1.

```
mydata<- data.frame(c(1:5))
```

The above code creates a dataframe

```
 X1.5
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
```

Lets see some commands

```
length(mydata)

[1] 1
```

To know the number of rows

case 1

```
nrow(mydata)
[1] 5
```

case 2: To know the number of elements in first column of a dataframe

```
length(mydata$X1.5)
[1] 5
length(mydata[[1]])
[1] 5
```

Length is used mostly for vectors and for dataframe it is good to use nrow command.

Regards,

Ganesh